# Unable to uninstall postgres completely from mac osx

Tags: macos, postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.1

I have completely unintsalled postgres and postgis from my system but still I am able to enter postgres through psql command . I need to uninstall completely because it is showing two psql and later I am able to reinstall afresh.

```
GW:~ User$ sudo -u postgres psql -h localhost
Password:
Password: 
psql (9.1.5, server 9.1.14)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

I don't understand how is it showing 9.1.5 and 9.1.14 . I need to get rid of this. Any help would be really grateful.

Comment: You could help by giving details of (1) how you (think you) installed PostgreSQL and (2) how you (think you) uninstalled it.

Comment: "*I don't understand how is it showing 9.1.5 and 9.1.14*" - you have an old version of the `psql` client in in the `$OATH$` of the user `postgres`, but the server that is running on your computer is already patched to 9.1.14. This is not a programming question. It should be moved to dba.stackexchange.com or superuser